Pigeon Hole Principle Proof
Prove using PHP that in any arrangement of the numbers $1,2,\ldots,20$ exist a sequence of $4$ numbers with sum of at least $42$.

I know there are $17$ different sequences of $4$ numbers in any arrangement,
and that the sum of each arrangement is between $10$ and $74$,
but i can't put my finger on what to use as the pigeons and what to use as the pigeonholes.

Thanks !.

To use the pigeonhole principle, you need to have something to divide (in this case look in the direction of sums of numbers), and some `holes' over which to divide the pigeons. But the holes have to be different from each other! The 17 subsets you suggest have overlappng numbers. Try to find some distinct sets. I hope that gives you a hint.

Ok i have something but i don't sure it is right, so the sum of all the numbers from 1 to 20 is 21*(20/2)=210 so if i divide that 210 pigeons to 5 holes of 4 i get 210/5=42 is it right? it was to simple lol

Ok so the number of Sequences is (20 choose 4) = 4845, that i get, as for what to do next i'm lost...

The question must mean "consecutive four".  Otherwise, just take $17+18+19+20>42$.

Your first comment, following the posted question, nails it.

This is much clearer with Dijkstra's interpretation of the PHP as "the maximum is at least the average". Splitting the arrangement into 5 sequences of length 4, the average sum of these sequences must be 210/5 = 42, so one of the sums must be at least 42.

From $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ to $a_{17},a_{18},a_{19},a_{20}$ there are $17$ sequences.  But not only must one of those add to at least $42$.  By @arkeets comment one of the $5$ sequences $a_1..., a_4$, $a_5...a_8$, $a_9.... a_{12}$, $a_{13}...a_{16}$ and $a_{17}...a_{20}$ must be at leas $42$.

We could consider the problem as groups of $4$ rooms in a hotel with total number of beds in each group of rooms as "pigeonholes"
Make such groups, working inwards symmetrically from both ends, viz (1,20,2,19), (3,18,4,17), (5,16,6,15),(7,14,8,13),(9,13,10,12)
We have by the process we adopted, been able to create five groups of 4  so that all of them have exactly 42 pigeonholes, so it is self-evident that if we reduce the number below 42 in one or more groups, the numbers in other groups will exceed $42$
thus it is proved that there must be at least one group of $4$ having at least $42$ pigeonholes

I really don't know why the answer has been downvoted !
